# Counterexample to infinite sum of expectations = sum of infinite expectations?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, expectation

I am looking for the counterexample to the statement $\sum E[X_n] = E[\sum X_n]$ given that $\sum E[X_n]$ and $\sum X_n$ exist. This would be also a counterexample to the dominated convergence theorem without one of its assumptions with the probability measure; I was able to create a counterexample using Lebesgue integral, but the domain is the entire real so it unfortunately fails.

Comment: The dominated convergence theorem is a theorem.  What do you mean by a counterexample to it?

Answer (score 3):

Is this the sort of thing you had in mind?

Take Lebesgue measure  on $[0,1]$.
For each positive integer $n$, let $X_n = 2^n$ on an interval of measure $2^{-1-n}$, $-2^{n}$ on an interval of measure $2^{-1-n}$, $0$ everywhere else, where all these intervals are pairwise disjoint (note that the sum of the measures of the 
intervals is $1$).  The pointwise sum $\sum_n X_n$ exists (and is finite) everywhere (in fact for any $x$ there is at most one $n$ for which $X_n(x) \ne 0$).  Also each $\mathbb E X_n = 0$, so $\sum_n \mathbb E X_n = 0$.  But $\mathbb E \sum_n X_n$ does not exist because $\sum_n X_n$ is not in $L^1$: $\mathbb E \left|\sum_n X_n\right| = \infty$.

Comment: all the sets and all the intervals are pairwise disjoint? or do you mean for each n the $set_n$ and the $interval_n$ are disjoint?

Comment: Sorry,, the "set" was meant to be an interval.  I'll edit.

Comment: Is this right? Consider $X_1, X_2, ...$ in $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \mathbb P) = ([0,1], \mathscr B([0,1]), \lambda)$ where

$$X_n = 2^n 1_{A_n} + -2^{n} 1_{B_n}$$ where $\lambda(A_n) = \frac{1}{2^n} = \lambda(B_n)$ and $A_n \cap B_n = \emptyset$

Comment: That's almost what I said (but $2^{-1-n}$ not $2^{-n}$, and all the $A_m$'s and $B_n$'s disjoint, not just for the same $n$).  And yes, it is right.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Robert Israel. 1 We have the collection $A = (A_1, A_2, ...)$ to be pairwise disjoint? 2 We have the collection $B = (B_1, B_2, ...)$ to be pairwise disjoint? 3 Is the collection $$A \cup B$$ pairwise disjoint?

Comment: All $A_i$ and $B_j$ are disjoint.